# Code for "Create a Client for Calculator Service" in documentation not working

Tags: ballerina

Sorry for asking a very basic question, I am new to Ballerina and do not really know how to proceed with this. I copy pasted the code in "Create a Client for Calculator Service" in the ballerina [documentation](https://ballerina.io/community-program/#install-ballerina) which is:

> import ballerina/http; import ballerina/io; import ballerina/log;
>
> endpoint http:Client clientEndpoint {
>       url: "http://localhost:9090" };
>
> function main(string... args) {
>
> ```
> http:Request req = new;
>
> // Set the JSON payload to the message to be sent to the endpoint.
> json jsonMsg = { a: 15.6, b: 18.9, operation: "add" };
> req.setJsonPayload(jsonMsg);
>
> var response = clientEndpoint->post("/calculator/operation", request = req);
> match response {
>     http:Response resp => {
>         var msg = resp.getJsonPayload();
>         match msg {
>             json jsonPayload => {
>                 string resultMessage = "Addition result " + jsonMsg["a"].toString() +
>                     " + " + jsonMsg["b"].toString() + " : " +
>                     jsonPayload["result"].toString();
>                 io:println(resultMessage);
>             }
>             error err => {
>                 log:printError(err.message, err = err);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     error err => { log:printError(err.message, err = err); }
> } }
> ```

Then when I run the below command in one console

> ballerina run calculator

and run the below command in another console

> ballerina run client.bal

I get the following error message:

> error: ./client.bal:17:20: not enough arguments in call to 'post()'
>   compilation contains errors

Shown below is the sample service code

> import ballerina/http;
>
> endpoint http:Listener listener {
>       port:9090 };
>
> // Calculator REST service @http:ServiceConfig { basePath:
>   "/calculator" } servicehttp:Service Calculator bind listener {
>
> ```
> // Resource that handles the HTTP POST requests that are directed to
> // the path `/operation` to execute a given calculate operation
> // Sample requests for add operation in JSON format
> // `{ "a": 10, "b":  200, "operation": "add"}`
> // `{ "a": 10, "b":  20.0, "operation": "+"}`
>
> @http:ResourceConfig {
>     methods: ["POST"],
>     path: "/operation"
> }
> executeOperation(endpoint client, http:Request req) {
>     json operationReq = check req.getJsonPayload();
>     string operation = operationReq.operation.toString();
>
>     any result = 0.0;
>     // Pick first number for the calculate operation from the JSON request
>     float a = 0;
>     var input = operationReq.a;
>     match input {
>         int ivalue => a = ivalue;
>         float fvalue => a = fvalue;
>         json other => {} //error
>     }
>
>     // Pick second number for the calculate operation from the JSON request
>     float b = 0;
>     input = operationReq.b;
>     match input {
>         int ivalue => b = ivalue;
>         float fvalue => b = fvalue;
>         json other => {} //error
>     }
>
>     if(operation == "add" || operation == "+") {
>         result = add(a, b);
>     }
>
>     // Create response message.
>     json payload = { status: "Result of " + operation, result: 0.0 };
>     payload["result"] = check <float>result;
>     http:Response response;
>     response.setJsonPayload(payload);
>
>     // Send response to the client.
>     _ = client->respond(response);
> } }
> ```

Can anyone help me understand what I have done wrong. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP client POST call in main function has to be changed as follows.

```
var response = clientEndpoint->post("/calculator/operation", req);
```

Since ballerina 0.975.0 version, the outbound request or the message is mandatory for  POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE. Therefore defaultable parameter is not required. Additionally, It allows to use payload directly as well.

```
//Request as message
http:Request req = new;
response = check clientEP->post("/test", req);

//Text payload
response = check clientEP->post("/test", "Sample Text");
```

For GET, HEAD and OPTIONS client calls,request or the message is optional. So when adding the request parameter, mention the defaultable parameter name as message. i.e message = req

```
//Request as message
http:Request req = new;
response = check clientEP->get("/test", message = req);

//Without any payload
response = check clientEP->get("/test");
```

Please refer [http-client](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-client-endpoint.html) and [Handling payload](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/different-payload-types.html) examples to understand the behavior of ballerina HTTP client and allowing different payload types